# how to group mixins of same kind in scss

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

i am using the following code

```scss
@use './rules.scss' as css;
@include css.mixin();
```

but i want to group mixins in my main file
foreg:- mixins containing rules for OS website layout should be in one group
and i can use them as

```scss
@include css.OS.windowmixin();
```

i have tried @group and nesting mixins as a suggestion from chatgpt but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can group your mixins in separate scss files inside a mixins folder like this:

```
mixins
  _group1Mixins.scss
  _group2Mixins.scss
```

Then create an `_index.scss` file in same folder that forwards all the mixin files by prefixing them:

```scss
@forward "_group1Mixins.scss" as group1-*;
@forward "_group2Mixins.scss" as group2-*;
```

Now in your main file you can import them using `@use`. The mixins from each file will be prefixed accordingly for example to use a mixin from your `_group1Mixins.scss` you will need to prefix it with `group1-`.

```scss
@use "mixins/index" as mixins;

.myclass {
  @include mixins.group1-myMixin();
}
```